# Creat Like Service That Keeps On Running When I Run Project

Tags: java, jsp

hi i am new towards development especially java i have created jsp page and when i run that jsp page i can perform the task that i need but i want it to run some thing like service    that when i run my project it will run my jsp page too but do not show any thing means jsp display .

Because i am just inserting data in data and there is nothing to display. Actually i am keep on ping some host in my jsp page by calling method in class that do it and keep on doing it automatically after some time by using

`"<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">`"

so it ping some host and insert its data in database

How would i do it like a service that it starts my desire work when i run project

Hopes for your Suggestions and please give some example to understand example code

Comment: you might want to explain by some example. it is hard to understand what you are asking\

Comment: @user1155394 - unfortunately, the combination of your poor English skills, the absence of any concrete details of your problem, and the absence of any clear questions makes this Question virtually unanswerable.

Answer (score 1):

What it sounds like is you have a JSP that inserts some data somewhere.  And you want a java process that repeatedly calls this JSP page.   This is a little odd, as I would java have the java process itself do the inserting and cut out the jsp middle-man, but whatever.

One very simple thing you can do is this:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class MyClass {

public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
   while (true) {
     URL myJSPURL = new URL("http://server/my.jsp");  //url for your jsp
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(myJSPURL.openStream())); //open cnonection
     while (in.readLine() != null);  //read the data from the connection, discard it
     in.close();
     System.sleep(5000);  //sleep 5 seconds
    }
}
}
```

Of course, this is very simple.  You can do more complex scheduling with a java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService

Comment: how would you execute your class ?? are you using it any where?

Comment: Change to the directory containing the compiled class and type "java MyClass" at the command prompt.